# Draw a plot for a matrix in r

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotrix

I have a matrix with three variables Row = Time, column = Date and the third variable Money which its value is an intersection of rows and columns. e.g. For `Time = 5` and `Date = 10`, Money is 12 and for `Time = 6` and `Date = 15`, Money is 15. I would like to draw the value of Money for the intersection of `x_axis = Time` and `Y_axis = Date`.

How to place Money in below?

```
plot.new()  
matplot(Time,Date, type = "p", lty = 1:5, lwd = 1, lend = par("lend"),col = 1,
        pch = 17 , xlab = "Time", ylab = "Date", xlim = range(0,40), ylim = range (0,120))
```

Comment: Hi! Can you please give us a subset of the matrix? thx

Comment: @Ale, hi. please see below the data.frame.                                       TIME DATE MONEY
10 12 15
17 19 23
15 16 14

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use `geom_raster` if you convert your data to a `data.frame` first:

```
ggplot(data, aes(Time, Date)) +
 geom_raster(aes(fill = Money))
```

See more on this here: http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_tile.html

---

*edit:*

see with random data here:

```
time <- c(1:100)
date <- c(1:100)
data <- expand.grid(TIME = time, DATE = date)

data$MONEY <- runif(1:10000, 0, 10)

ggplot(data, aes(TIME, DATE)) +
  geom_raster(aes(fill = MONEY), interpolate = F)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for the comment but it I need a point rather than a rectangular.

Comment: I don't understand what you want - if you want a scatter plot, you can use this with the example data above: `ggplot(data, aes(TIME, DATE)) + geom_point(aes(color = MONEY))`

Comment: The problem is that this formula takes the value of the intersection of Time and Date. While I want to draw the value of Money for each Time-Date intersection.